# Not able to fix PagerTitleStrip in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

The PagerTitleStrip is overflowing. I am not able to see all the title at a time. Not able to make out what i am missing here. I have attached the screenshots.
[image: PageTitleStripExample - 3 titles are not seen at the same time.]

Also how do i add material UI theme to these tabs. which library  is required and how to i apply the theme for the tab or for the entire application

My adapter code

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
int totalFragments = 3;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MyFragment.newInstance(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalFragments;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return "Tab One";
    case 1:
        return "Tab Two";
    case 2:
        return "Tab Three";
}

return null;
}
}
```

Layout file:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip" 
            android:scrollbarSize="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is not your entire layout xml. Please submit all of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, where you have used `fill_parent`, replace those with `match_parent`, since filling is deprecated.

Second, the common settings for `ViewPager` size are

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
```

and possibly

```
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

After these, for your `PagerTitleStrip`, try

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Third, The material way of designing tabbed vies is with `TabLayout`, which Google has some tutorials and examples for.